# Ordered pair of Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is meaning of ordered pair of rational numbers, or ordered pair of integers, or real numbers??

In case of pegion-hole principle , we used this word "ordered pair", Can we say symmetric pair (a,b),(b,a) is an ordered pair and without any relation (a,b) also an ordered pair??

Comment: Are you referring to this [Ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) ?

Comment: An "ordered pair" is a *pair* (a couple of objects) where is relevant to know which is "first" and which "second", like e.g. in the relation "father-son".

Comment: If we use the $xy$-cartesina plane, we identipy points with ordered pairs of real numebrs : $(x,y)$; we use order in order to avoid mixing the $x$ coordinate with the $y$ one.

Comment: Can u give an example of rational number for this?

Comment: Point $P$ of coordinates $(\dfrac 1 2 , \dfrac 3 4)$.

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition of the ordered pair of a and b is
(a,b) = { {a}, {a,b} }.
It has the property (exercise)
(a,b) = (u,v) iff a = u, b = v.
That property is the essence of ordered pairs.

As you see, it is definable for any two things regardless of their nature even if it includes an order.
It also does not order a and b though one usually considers a as the first, just like the convention that the x-axis is the 1st coordinate.
{a,b} = {b,a} is an unordered pair lacking the essential property for ordered pairs.

The symmetric pair (a,b), (b,a) is not an ordered pair.
It is two separate ordered pairs,
((a,b), (b,a)) is an ordered pair of ordered pairs.
The notation (a,b) is also used for open intervals.
So be aware of the context.

Comment: I have not got clearly. Can u give some example of it to get it more clear

Comment: (math book, teacher) @Srestha

Comment: yes , that is ok . But suppose, I have taken more complex example like a=b mod 5. and c=d mod 7- then ordered pair for (a,b) will be (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)......(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),..........(4,5),(4,6). right?? i.e.among elements of a set i.e a, b  there may be no relation. But they can be related to some other factors. right??@William

Comment: @Srestha.  Wrong.

Comment: why wrong? @William

Comment: @Srestha.  A list of solutions for two different equations is not an ordered pair.   It is a list of ordered pairs.